# Generate repeating data based on date range

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a view with result like this in SQL Server,

from data table with date range per row (start date - end date), can generate repeating data based on a date range to get the number of months for repeating data (by displaying the date of the beginning of each month).

### data table

| name | Debt | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 2022-01-24 | 2022-03-31 |
| B | 50 | 2022-01-17 | 2022-02-28 |
| C | 80 | 2023-02-06 | 2023-02-28 |

### result view

| name | Debt | Checkpoint Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 2023-01-01 | 2022-03-31 |
| A | 100 | 2023-02-01 | 2022-03-31 |
| A | 100 | 2023-03-01 | 2022-03-31 |
| B | 50 | 2023-01-01 | 2022-02-28 |
| B | 50 | 2023-02-01 | 2022-02-28 |
| C | 80 | 2023-02-01 | 2023-02-28 |

Can it be creating using View without creating a function?

Comment: `JOIN` to your calendar table and you are 90% of the way there. What have you tried so far? Why isn't it working?

Comment: I must admit, however, it seems odd that the first row for your dates is always the 1st, even though it's not in your original data.

Comment: @ThomA if use JOIN with calendar table, how we can get next month from date range?
for checkpoint date is always set to 1st date of each month from date range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a recursive CTE, they are slow. Use `GENERATE_SERIES` (or on older version there are similar user-defined functions you can create).

```sql
SELECT
  d.name,
  d.Debt,
  StartDate = DATEADD(month, g.value, DATETRUNC(month, d.StartDate)),
  d.EndDate
FROM data d
CROSS APPLY GENERATE_SERIES(0, DATEDIFF(month, d.StartDate, d.EndDate)) g;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/sj_sTeEv)

Comment: using GENERATE_SERIES is indeed fast, but I can't use GENERATE_SERIES because I use Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8, Invalid object name 'GENERATE_SERIES'.

Comment: after I check my sql server compatibility level is only 150, I need to increase it to 160 to be able to use GENERATE_SERIES @charlieface

Comment: There are other options if you don't want to up your compat level (which I recommend you should) see https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1#

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this using a recursive CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT name, debt, DATETRUNC(month, start_date) AS start_date, end_date
    FROM mytable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT m.name, m.debt, DATEADD(month, 1, c.start_date), m.end_date
    FROM mytable m
    JOIN cte c ON c.name = m.name
                  AND DATEADD(month,1,c.start_date) < m.end_date
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
ORDER BY name, start_date;
```

Results :

```
name    debt    start_date  end_date
A       100     2022-01-01  2022-03-31
A       100     2022-02-01  2022-03-31
A       100     2022-03-01  2022-03-31
B       50      2022-01-01  2022-02-28
B       50      2022-02-01  2022-02-28
C       80      2023-02-01  2023-02-28
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/6-2R7IfR)

Comment: Beautiful, exactly the result. Thank you @selvazi

Comment: Recursive CTEs are slow, use `GENERATE_SERIES` or similar instead.